# Not being able to access Flow variable in Apex class

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, compile-error, visual-flows

I am trying to create a flow which creates an account record and then navigates to the newly created record detail page

VF Code

```
<apex:page Controller="AccFlowController" TabStyle="Account">
<br/>
<flow:interview name="CreateAccount" interview="{!myflow}" finishlocation="{!AID}" />
```

Apex Class code

```
 public class AccFlowController{

 public Flow.Interview.Quick_Account myFlow { get; set; }

 public String getmyID() {
 if (myFlow==null) return '';
  else return myFlow.accountId;
 }

 public PageReference getOID(){
 PageReference p = new PageReference('https://dev-dev ed.my.salesforce.com/'+getmyID());
 p.setRedirect(true);
 return p;
 }

}
```

However, when I try to save the class it is showing

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: accountId

My flow has the following variable present

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation on **[Getting Flow Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_visualworkflow_vars.htm)**, you should call `myFlow.getVariableValue`:

```
String accountId = (String)myFlow.getVariableValue('accountId');
```

Comment: I tried it as well. But (String)myFlow.getVariableValue('accountId'); just fetches null even though the record is successfully created. @AdrianLarson

Comment: That seems like a problem with your flow, not your Apex. This answer resolves what you were doing wrong in the code you posted.

Comment: You were right. There was an issue with my flow. All I needed was a finish screen